How to repair small holes and tears in waterproof backing paper behind stucco
I’m remodeling the bathroom.  The bathroom is by the exterior wall.  When I pulled an uneven stud out, it dislodged some nails from plaster and caused some small holes and tears on the black waterproof barrier.  The stud is about 3-4 feet under the window.  How do I repair the hole and tears? The exterior wall is somewhat protected from rain and weather because it’s by the deck where there is roof extended so I think the rain is not going to be a big problem and I live in LA.  But I would want to patch it up as precaution.  Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Chimichanga, what is the waterproof barrier? Is it polyethylene sheeting or a membrane of some sort? That matters.
